# Qt missing qtextcontrol_p.h

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, qt5

I am converting a Qt project in version 4.4 to 5.5. I am using visual studio 2013. In a cpp file I include #include "private/qtextcontrol_p.h" it says cannot open source file. When i check my Qt 5.5 folder that file is not there but it is in my 4.4 folder. Has that file been removed from Qt 5.5?

Comment: It's strange that you made your solution based on implementatiion details of Qt.

Answer (score 1):

That file has been moved or removed. Qt 4.4 is no longer supported. You need to read the Qt 4.x to 5.x porting guide to find out which equivalent control you need to use.

Moreover, the `<private/qtextcontrol_p.h` is inner the PIMPL implementation of  class. You shouldn't be using the private version of the header file directly in your code. Rather use `<QTextControl>` instead.